# ServeRAID M5015 Controller upgrading hard disks without downtime or data loss?

Tags: raid5, ibm

The configuration is as follows:

**13 x 450G disks on RAID5 with 1 hot spare.**

*There 2 more disks but configured as RAID1.*

Is it possible to upgrade the hard disks without downtime or data loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like only M1115 supports hot swap and M5015 does not.

www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/tips0054.html

Comment: What will happen if I change the hot spare with a bigger hard disk?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve by replacing the hot spare with a larger drive? Are ok doing this offline since your RAID controller does not support hot swap. Your RAID may not allow expanding one drive with a larger capacity since they expect them to be of equal capacity.

Comment: Updating the capacity of the SAN without downtime. Is it possible to do this with an expansion unit?

Comment: If this is your SAN then I strongly recommend you spek to IBM support and seek advice. This controller supports 32 SATA/SAS drives. You may also add an expansion unit but I'm unsure if you can do this without downtime.